# Nested If shows #VALUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have below formula. Its working for two first conditions.

```
=IF(F3="","",IF(F3="RUB",IF(FIND("2600",J3),MID(J3,FIND("2600",J3),14)),
 IF(F3<>"RUB",IF(FIND(":59:",J3),MID(J3,FIND(":59:",J3)+5,14),
 IF(F3<>"RUB",IF(FIND(":59F",J3),MID(J3,FIND(":59F",J3)+6,14)
  ))))))
```

but if if met below condition , it shows #VALUE!

```
IF(F3<>"RUB",IF(FIND(":59F",J3),MID(J3,FIND(":59F",J3)+6,14)
```

Is there any suggestions how to get it work?I tried to combine with OR and with IFERROR, but give no result.

Comment: You probably want to tag a programming language here... even if it's excel.

Comment: Thanks, Henk Holterman)

Comment: Could you add a minimum sample table that reproduces this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still some 'holes' in your logic that were not covered by either your formula or narrative. These will return FALSE. However, this is closer to what you are trying to accomplish.

```
=IF(F3="", "", IF(F3="RUB", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("2600", J3)), MID(J3, FIND("2600", J3), 14)),
               IF(F3<>"RUB", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(":59:", J3)), MID(J3, FIND(":59:", J3)+5, 14),
                             IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(":59F", J3)), MID(J3, FIND(":59F", J3)+6, 14))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem with this:

```
IF(F3<>"RUB",IF(FIND(":59F",J3),MID(J3,FIND(":59F",J3)+6,14)
```

Is that the search text `:59F` cannot be found in the cell `J3`. If you change to this:

```
IF(F3<>"RUB",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(":59F",J3)),MID(J3,FIND(":59F",J3)+6,14)
```

It should fix the problem.

**EDIT** *shorter solution*

```
IF(F3<>"RUB",IFERROR(MID(J3,FIND(":59F",J3)+6,14)
```

---

On a side note, your `IF(F3<>"RUB",...)` is superfluous because you already have a previous condition `IF(F3="RUB",...)`, so it is a given that `F3<>"RUB"` if it didn't make it past the first condition.

Comment: Very interesting about superfluous "IF(F3<>"RUB",...)", thanks!